# How don't duplicate the dataSource in Spring xml files?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have two files which contain the dataSource definitions. There are /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml and src/main/resources/hibernateContext.xml

it's my dataSource definition:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fullproject"
            p:username="root"
            p:password="admin" />
```

This definition is necessary in every file for using with different services; Can i don't duplicate this code and only definite it only in one place????

Comment: Why would that be needed? The one defined in the `applicationContext.xml` is enough. All the others can be removed. Not sure why they would even be there.

Comment: but if I want to use  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hibernateContext.xml"); I can't get this xml file if it will be reside in /WEB-INF/ directory. Is it true?

Comment: You don't want to use that you should never create a new context yourself, that in fact is even quite dangerous (unless you prefer a memory hogging, transactionally weird and eventually crawling application)...

Comment: Ok i try to explain my situation. I have applicationContext that resides in /WEB-INF/ to implement my Spring Security that wants to get the dataSource bean. Also I have the hibernateContext in src/main/resources which will use LocalSessionFactoryBean that wants to get the dataSource bean too. What is the properly resolve in this situation???

Comment: That can just access the bean available in the `applicationContext.xml`. They are either both loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` or (infrastructure should be globally available). Or by the `DispatcherServlet` which can access the parent context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. You don't want  to import the xml again as that would lead to bean duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to factor out commons snippets into dedicated Spring XML file and then include them like this:

```
<!-- Import shared bean definitions -->
<import resource="classpath:shared.env.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two "dataSource" beans can be shared. So you only need one definition.
In your web.xml, load the "master" configuration file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
        classpath*:/hibernateContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```